# Scheduler task indefinite time duration on Windows Server 2003/2008

Tags: windows, scheduling

```
Schtasks /create /s $server /ru $user /rp $password /tn $taskName /sc MINUTE /mo $intervalMin /tr $cmd
```

This command creates a task in scheduler to be executed each minute.

- On Windows Server 2008 duration is 'Indefinite'
- On Windows Server 2003 duration is '1 day'

How to resolve this weird behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to create the task this way:

```
schtasks /create /s $server /sd $startdate /st $starttime /ru $user /rp $password /tn $taskName /sc daily /mo $scheduleDays /tr $cmd /RI $intervalMin /DU $duration
```

Create daily task, set /RI = 1 (minute) and /DU = "24:00" /mo = 1(day)

The task will be executed forever each minute on Server 2003‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎
‎‎‎‎‎‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎